# Matrix of a transformation with respect to bases a and b

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Let $T:R^2\to R^2$ be the linear transformation $T:R^2\to R^2$ given by
$$T\begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\
x_2
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
-3x_1-3x_2 \\
6x_1-x_2
\end{bmatrix}$$

(Pretend that's a 2x1 matrix - I'm too tired to figure this out.)

Given that a is the standard basis of $R^2$, and b is the basis of $R^2$ consisting of: 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
-1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
-3 \\
1
\end{bmatrix}

What is the change of basis matrix from a to b and the change of basis matrix from b to a?

**What I keep getting**
For the change of basis matrix from a to b, I've gone through each step multiple times in different ways and constantly get:
\begin{bmatrix}
21/2 & 3 \\
9/2 & 2
\end{bmatrix}
This is apparently incorrect, and I can't figure out why. How and where am I going wrong? Even more baffling is for the change of basis matrix from b to a, I get
\begin{bmatrix}
0  & 6 \\
5  & 17 
\end{bmatrix}
and that is also incorrect. Yet when I used that exact matrix in another part of the question (not shown here), that part was correct! What exactly is going on here?

EDIT: Made the matrices look like matrices.

Comment: Welcome to math.se!  The best way to get a helpful answer is to post one of your failed attempts so that people can tell you what you did wrong.

Comment: ...and [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference/5023#5023) is how to set matrices - it's easy once you try!

Comment: Note that the information about $T$ is completely irrelevant to the question of finding the change of basis matrices. That question just involves $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Um, yes it is relevant. I'm looking for the matrix of T, after all.

Comment: You may well be looking for that matrix, but you never say so. You say you are looking for the change of basis matrix from a to b, and from b to a, and neither of those questions has the least bit to do with the details of the transformation $T$.

Answer (score 0):

Let the two vectors in $B$ be $\vec v_1$ and $\vec v_2$. Then $\underset{B \leftarrow A}{P}$ (the change of basis matrix from $A$ to $B$) can be found by forming the augmented matrix $[B \mid A]$ and row-reducing to $[I \mid \underset{B \leftarrow A}{P}]$.

Alternatively, we can notice by inspection that:
\begin{align*}
\vec v_1 + \vec v_2 = -2\vec e_1 \\
3\vec v_1 + \vec v_2 = -2\vec e_2
\end{align*}

Hence, it follows that:
$$
\underset{B \leftarrow A}{P}
= [[\vec e_1]_B ~~ [\vec e_2]_B]
= \begin{bmatrix}
-1/2 & -3/2 \\
-1/2 & 1/2
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Alternatively, we could notice that since $A$ is just the standard basis, it follows that $B = \underset{A \leftarrow B}{P}$ so that:
$$
\underset{B \leftarrow A}{P}
= (\underset{A \leftarrow B}{P})^{-1}
= B^{-1}
= \frac{1}{1 \cdot 1 - (-3) \cdot (-1)}\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & -1 \\
-3 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$